# How to access the values from a JArray?

Tags: c#, json.net

My `JArray` is in the following format:

```
jArray = {"data": [
  {
    "Id": 29288,
    "SourceURL": "hhfythhs\\fg\d$",
    "TargetURL": "testURL@xyz.com",
    "Site_Owner_Email_IDs": "emu@xyz.com",
    "siteId": null
  },
  {
    "Id": 30724,
    "SourceURL": "\\\\jnjphmafps1\\home$\\nriver46",
    "TargetURL": "testURL@xyz.com",
    "Site_Owner_Email_IDs": "emu@xyz.com, kite@xyz.com",
    "siteId": null
  }
]}
```

I'm trying to access the `Site_Owner_Email_IDs` value with the following code:

```
foreach (var item in jArray)
{
    emailIDsoe = (string)item.Value["data"][0]["Site_Owner_Email_IDs"];
}
```

which is giving me an error:

> Accessed JArray values with invalid key value: "data". Int32 array index expected.

How can I access the key `Site_Owner_Email_IDs` and its value for each item in `jArray`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `jArray` is actually a `JObject` which contains a `JArray` (in the `data` property).

Try it like this:

```
foreach (var item in jArray["data"])
{
    emailIDsoe = (string)item["Site_Owner_Email_IDs"];
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/tzcXql